# How to disable a DropDownList when a checkbox is checked in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

In a view, I have 2 checkbox and DropDownList.

I want when I check the checkbox, the DropDownList and the other checkbox became **DISABLED.**

I use a javascript in order to do that.

The checkbox is perfect , it became disabled but I still have a problem with DropDownList.

This is the code :

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" />Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>

<div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems); ID = "dd"%></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

         function test2() {
             var chkMain = document.getElementById('chkMain');
             var chkFirst = document.getElementById('chkFirst');
             var dd = document.getElementById('dd');

             if (chkFirst.checked) {
                 chkMain.disabled = 'disabled';
                 dd.disabled = 'disabled';

             }
             else {
                 chkMain.disabled = false;

             }
         }

    </script>
```

I had a Compilation Error in the line of DropDownList

Comment: Can you post any details of the error?

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error:
<div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems); ID = "dd"%></div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems); ID = "dd"%>
```

This is invalid syntax. If you wish to assign an id to the dropdown list, then use an anonymous type:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.PosteSuivantSelected, Model.PostesItems, new { @id = "dd" });
```